# How to ignore jinja2 braces {{}} in j2 template file

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have a j2 file that i want to edit and copy to my remote server (as apart of my ansible play). The file has several 3 variables indicated by braces `{{ }}`. How can I only target the 2nd variable named `{{ bar }}` and ignore the other 2 in the file so they're left alone and copied to my remote server? For example, my test.j2 file contains:

```
line 1 {{ foo }}
line 2 {{ bar }}
line 3 {{ foo2 }}
```

Can I explicitly address `{{ bar }}` variable in my ansible playbook? If so, how would i write it (syntactically) in my ansible playbook?

Answer (score 9):

What follows isn't something I would recommend, but if you need to template only `bar` and nothing else (or if `bar` is always templated first before the rest), you can probably use the `{% raw %}` block:

```
{% raw %}line 1 {{ foo }}{% endraw %}
line 2 {{ bar }}
{% raw %}line 3 {{ foo2 }}{% endraw %}
```

Basically the idea is to mark non-bar variables as raw so that jinja doesn't template them.

Answer (score 3):

yet another alternative:

```
line 1 {{ '{{foo}}' }}
line 2 {{ bar }}
line 3 {{ '{{foo2}}' }}
```

Comment: This is the tidiest one here, should be the accepted answer! Thanks

Comment: Where is this documented? I could not find it, and it did not work for me

Comment: You can find the documentation here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping. All answers here are variants of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{% raw %}` block as @bow mentions or there's also a shorthand for smaller chunks of code, it's shorter but not necessarily more readable than just using a raw block.

```
line 1 {{ '{{' }} foo {{ '}}' }}
line 2 {{ bar }}
line 3 {{ '{{' }} foo {{ '}}' }}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#escaping